# Wcf Bindings in Wan

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wshttpbinding

I am using WCF in Wan.The basic activity of WCF is Database Synchronization.
Therefore the performance is critical.Currently I am using wsHttpBindings.
Is there any other optimized option which shall survive the Wan and Latency Options?